# Trying to run my first linkedlist program in java and IntelliJ Idea throws these errors

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is to traverse through the LinkedList and then print out. I tried Googling what might be wrong but no luck till now. I already apologize if this is stupid question.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {
    Node head;
    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node( int d ) {
            this.data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public void printList(){
        Node n = head;
        while(n != null) {
            System.out.print(n.data + " ");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
        llist.head = new Node(1);
        Node second = new Node(2);
        Node third = new Node(3);
        llist.head.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        llist.printList();
    }
}
```

[Error upon compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXETk.png)

[Current file warnings and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipEdO.png)

Comment: what exactly are "these errors"?

Comment: @Twistleton call an instance method as a static one?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Create your own `LinkedList`? Practice using `java.util.LinkedList`? The current snippet as is, looks like you are trying to mix the two.

Comment: Upon doing that, giving this (https://graph.org/file/9499db0805881cc780425.png) @Twistleton

Comment: printList is not a function of LinkedList. Or will you create your own LinkedList?

Comment: Trying to create my own @Twistleton

Comment: @maloomeister to create and then travserse

Comment: java: class LinkedList is public, should be declared in a file named LinkedList.java @maloomeister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't really clear about what you were trying to do here. Are you trying to create an own implementation of a linked list? Or are you simply trying to play around with `java.util.LinkedList`?

With the information gathered from your comments, we can tell that you are in fact trying to create your own implementation of a linked list.

So there are a few steps to take to fix your code. Firstly, remove the `import java.util.LinkedList`, as you apparently don't actually want to use that.

Then rename your outer class (which is currently `Main`) to something that makes sense, i.e. `MyLinkedList`. (Also don't forget to also rename the .java file)

```
public class MyLinkedList {
    Node head;
    ...
```

Then in your `main` method, you need to actually use **your** implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyLinkedList llist = new MyLinkedList();
    ...
}
```

Then, you should be able to work forward from here.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the error start as from the line

```java
llist.head = new Node (1);
```

Because `head` is not defined in`LinkedList`.

You must review the documentation of `LinkedList` and the existing methods